# "Computer is not a member of My" Error in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

This error is exceptionally annoying.  I've done various searches, and have been able to fix this issue.  I am one of several developers on the application and the only one with the issue.  I've fixed it before temporarily by adding an extension to the My Extensions panel in the project's properties (which generates a different error) and then removing that new extension.  That made the error go away.  Flaky, eh?

Anyway:

```
If Not My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
    ISConnectedToNetwork = False
    ...
End If
```

Gives the error:

> 'Computer' is not a member of 'My'.

Clarification Edit: This is in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this little bug in another messed up and probably temporary way.

Working off of Pete's insight, I set the project's **Application Type** from **Class Library** to **Windows Forms Application**.

I did a build at this point which failed due to some error about not having "Main" implemented.  Okay, so I set it back to Class Library.

Built again.  Success.

***SIGH***

Answer (score 6):

The "My" namespace exposes properties in the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices(v=vs.110).aspx) If you have a Class Library project then `My.computer` and `My.Network` etc are not available because Visual Studio didn't instantiate them for you. A simple work-around is to instantiate them yourself.

```
Dim MyNetwork = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network
Debug.Print(MyNetwork.Ping("MyServerName"))

Dim MyComputer = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer
Debug.Print(MyComputer.Name)

If Not MyComputer.Network.IsAvailable Then
    ISConnectedToNetwork = False

End If
```

Etc...

Comment: Why I try this, I get `BC30002 Type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer' is not defined`.

Comment: Marcin later answered his own question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78151558/2559297

Answer (score 4):

In visual studio, go to project -> project properties -> my extensions -> add extension -> select "web my extension" in case of web services/ web site. It resolved my issue.

Comment: For WPF Applications, use the "WPF my extension"

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you're using .NET 4.0?  If so, are you using the client profile?  I've run into situations where I KNOW what want is properly referenced and available only to be told it doesn't exist at compile time because I had the project set to client profile, which only allows a subset of the framework to be used.

Comment: Found this too, looks like My morphs around quite a bit based on project type:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172698(VS.80).aspx




According to the matrix in that link, if you used an empty project this would be expected behavior.

What error did you receive when you added the extension?

Comment: It's not in .NET 4.0, it's in 2.0.  It seems plausible that it could have been created as an empty project and that's why--it's a good theory--but I cannot confirm as it predates me.  Any ideas on fixing it?

Comment: I'm not up to speed on monkeying around with My extensions, but that seems to be the right place to look.  What was the error you got when you added the extension?  If I were to hazard a pot shot at the issue, I'd be looking at the .vbproj to see what happens when you modify the extensions.  I might just do that if this is still unanswered this evening...

Comment: Well predictably I'm unable to replicate my magic fix.  *Sigh*  I'm thinking that you're right about the whole blank project thing.  What gets me is that I'm the only person that gets it, and I only get it sometimes, having fixed it by either the extension hack or restarting visual studio a couple times.  Isn't that the typical Microsoft Way?

Comment: I'd say keep a really close eye on that .vbproj again.  See if it's any different when you're getting errors vs no errors.  Rule out physical changes to that file as a the culprit.  If it DOES change then I'd start trying to rule out source control shenanigans.

Comment: Did a file compare before and after fix.  No change in the .vbproj file.

Comment: Are you sure?  If you changed the project type it should have at least changed the <OutputType> element... ?  Edit:  Cracked open a new vbproj and I think what you're after is the <MyType> setting.

Comment: What I compared was the initial errored state to the switched-back state without error.  So there's no change in the vbproj between the Class Library state with error, and the Class Library state without.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by state...  Changing the project type should change <OutputType>.  I did a quick test and extensions look to be tracked as additional <ItemGroup> elements with <Compile> instructions specifiying a VBMyExtensionTemplateID and a VBMyExtensionTemplateVersion.  Are you not seeing that too?

Comment: I'm comparing the initial vbproj file when it has the error to the vbproj file after I've changed it to a different project type and back (with no error), and there's no changes that would explain why there was an error before and isn't after switching the type and back.  Hope that makes sense.  Kind of an awkward thing to put into words. :)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @D_Bester [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48451182/248823), I was getting error:

```
BC30002 Type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer' is not defined
```

To solution was to go to (in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022) to `Project -> <name>_Properties` and then

[image]

And then

[image]

And finally

[image]