# Why is My.Computer not working in visual basic .NET console app?

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

Why isn't this working. I tried this on a school computer (fully reimaged and running on a network) and it worked fine
Yet, when I try it on my home pc (newly installed visual studio 2019)
it throws the exception:

> Computer is not a member of projectname. My

Code is here:

```
Imports System

Module Program

Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("D:\\story1.txt")
    Dim stringReader As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim TotalString As String = ""
    While stringReader <> "*"
        stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            TotalString += stringReader
        End If
    End While
    Console.WriteLine(TotalString)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: It's not possible to say why it worked "*on a school computer*" and not on your "*home pc*" without knowing more about each environment and how this code was executed on each.

Comment: Duplicate of [“Computer is not a member of My” Error in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238213/computer-is-not-a-member-of-my-error-in-net/11202744)

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: Be sure to pick the correct project template to get started.  You need "Console App (.NET Framework).  Not .NET Core, its My namespace is quite empty.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry about this - I was using the wrong type of application. I used type Console app .NET core instead of Console app .NET Framework
I apologize for any inconvenience.