# Visual Studio 2019 .NET Core 3.0 'Computer is not a member of Testing.My'

Tags: visual-studio-2019

This has been a very annoying problem that I have been suppressing but I decided I need to find a fix for it. Its not just the 'Computer is not a member of Testing.My' problem, but 'Computer' doesn't even show up in the intellisense when I type 'My'. Before anyone says to look on the internet for the solution to the problem, I have... and none of them help. I am a beginner, and I may be making myself look like an imbecile, but any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseEnter
        My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Beep)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching tirelessly for an answer to this I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48451182/15016928). So, give thanks to [D_Bester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2559297/d-bester) if this helps.

Try instantiating a new `Computer`.

```vb
    Public Class YourForm

        ' Declare it private if you do not have a reason to use it in any of your other classes.
        Public Computer As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer

        ''' <Summary>
        ''' Plays the Beep sound, from within <see cref="Media.SystemSounds"/>, when the <see cref="Form.MouseEnter"/> event is raised.
        ''' </Summary>
        Private Sub Form1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseEnter
            Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Beep)
        End Sub

    End Class
```